# Band pass filter , component values

Tags: active-filter, band-pass

The input of the band pass filter is 30Khz triangular wave of 1Vpp. I want the band pass filter to allow 27k-33k Hz . I have used these values based on the formulas I found online for this band pass filter.

[image]

Unfortunately the problem seems to be , that at high frequencies eg. 60kHz it does not cut them off and the second problem that it reduces the 1Vpp to 500mV Vpp which I don't want either.

This is with input of 30khz(in green ) and band pass output (in blue)
[image]

And this is with 60kHz input (same colours)

[image]

To me it seems they are the same, which is bad. What I am doing wrong , which values should I use

ps. the formulas for the values I used are on this site http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_7.html

Comment: You're going to need a much higher order filter than what you have if you want to have good attenuation of a signal only 1 octave above the LPF cut-off frequency.

Comment: @ThePhoton I am using a second order low pass filter after this band pass , but I am specifically told to use a band pass filter that does the things I mention in my question . There has to be a combination of capacitors and resistors that accomplish this

Comment: Are you not allowed to use inductors? Remember we only know as much about your problem as you actually tell us.

Comment: @ThePhoton No its only RC, I know I am trying to provide as much information to be clear

Comment: What is your requirement for attenuation at 60 kHz?

Comment: @ThePhoton I just need the peak to peak , to be low so that we can say the filter cuts the high frequencies

Comment: Try the **Infinite Gain Multiple Feedback Active Filter** type bandpass filter, on the same tutorial page. Design for high Q >>1. This may require a fast high-frequency op amp, because the gain will be quite high. Because it is very frequency-selective, component values will be fussy too.

Comment: "Low" is not an engineering specification. You need to have a quantitative spec like "at least 10x attenuation" or "at least 4x attenuation" before you or anybody else can design this filter.

Comment: @ThePhoton okay , I suppose 4x attenuation is what I need

Answer (score 2):

The filter you have is the simplest kind of bandpass filter. Really it's just a high-pass filter cascaded with a low-pass filter. So long as you keep within the op-amp's operating frequency range, there will be little interaction between the low-pass components and the high-pass components.

So to block the 60-kHz signal, you're relying on a first-order low-pass filter. A first order filter can only achieve 6 dB per octave roll-off, so you shouldn't expect more than a factor of 2 difference in the output voltage between 30 kHz and 60 kHz with this design.

If you want to provide more attenuation in the stop-band at one octave above the pass-band, you will need a higher order filter.

First, you need to decide your specification: What is the minimum acceptable attenuation at 60 kHz.

Then look for a design that can meet your specification. This might be a higher-order low-pass filter, or it might be a (higher-order) band-pass filter actually designed as a band-pass rather than low-pass plus high-pass.

Comment: Honestly, the OP may need to use all 4 sections of a quad op-amp. 24 dB per octave may have to be good enough with analog filters.

Comment: @Sparky256, now they say they only need 4x attenuation at 60 kHz, so they might not need to go that far.

Comment: Well at least the quad package gives the OP that option, if needed.